# Flutter xlider can't set min and max value by variable

Tags: flutter, slider

I am trying to set the minimum and maximum values of a slider from a Bloc. When I try to set the value using a variable, I get an error.

[image: error screenshot]

But when I fix the value of min and max, it works.

Here's the code I'm using:

```dart
FlutterSlider(
          values: [state.startPointSliderValue, state.endPointSliderValue],
          rangeSlider: true,
          tooltip: FlutterSliderTooltip(
            positionOffset:
                FlutterSliderTooltipPositionOffset(top: -11, left: 10),
            custom: (value) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 44,
                width: 47,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 44,
                    width: 47,
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      color: state.disableSlider == false
                          ? BaseColors.allPrimaryPrimary90.withOpacity(0.8)
                          : BaseColors.neutralDisabled,
                      shape: MessageBorder(),
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Container(
                        child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              // left: 8,
                              bottom: 8), //apply padding to all four sides
                          child: Text(
                            (value.toInt()).toString()
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          max: state.defaultEndPoint, //error
          min: state.defaultStartPoint, //error
          // max: 47, // it's work
          // min: 1, //it's work
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```